# iOS library for download file & resume download

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to create a function to download a file & resume it if it's disconnected.

I looked at [asyncsocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) library, but it doesn't provide a resuming capabilities.

Are there any other library out there for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). See [Resuming interrupted downloads](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use).

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest does not work properly in iOS5, and the developer is no longer maintaining the project.  You should not be using ASIHTTPRequest in new projects.

Comment: So BBonifield, know of any alternatives? I really don't want to have to write this from scratch if there is some alternative, and googlien yields little.

Comment: BBonifield can you explain what is not working for you using ASIHTTPRequest ? I know the developer is not maintaining it but so far I dont found any problem using it in iOS-5.0.

Comment: I get an error when app return back from background. I guess this is the problem in iOS 5. Am I right?